# Code duplication with exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've noticed a few places in the code I'm maintaining where there is identical code in an exist and a result set.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT a, b, c 
          FROM table
          WHERE d = 2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT a, b, c
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE d = 2
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'EMPTY'
    END
```

Is there a nice way to rewrite the above so the select isn't duplicated?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers so far.  The consensus seems to be that the consuming applications should be modified, but, unfortunately, I don't control these applications.

As for the answers stating that this is dangerous since the select or exists may be modified independently of the other I completely agree, and that is actually what prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: @Joshua: I think you mistyped.  that /d should have been a /s

Comment: I'd have thought it needs an app change.  Why can't the application just handle an empty result set itself?  I've never seen this pattern of returning a singleton result set 'EMPTY' instead of just an empty result set.

Comment: @asc99c I've seen this "pattern" on this site many times recently.

Comment: Under conditions of concurrency there is absolutely no guarantee that the result of the `EXISTS` query will still be true at the time of the `SELECT` anyway. So the `EXISTS` could return true but then that `d=2` row gets deleted by another transaction and your application still needs to deal with an empty result set!

Answer (score 2):

Just do the select, and fix the application so it doesn't check for `RS(0) = 'empty'` - most application languages can deal with an empty resultset just fine. This kind of query is very wasteful - never mind potentially dangerous (for example - someone edits the `EXISTS()` part but forgets to replicate that change to the actual `SELECT`, or vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I agree with the previous posters that there's no satisfyingly good way to do this.

If your main goal is to eliminate duplicated code, you can move to the following pattern:

```
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  c
INTO #temp
FROM table
WHERE d = 2

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT 'EMPTY'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #TEMP
END

DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```

Of course this solution has it's own potential set of issues, and I think you'd be far better off modifying your consuming application to eliminate the problem alltogether.